# Is there a way to add new columns to R based on conditions to

Tags: r, azure

Currently using R in Azure. I'm trying to create a new column within my dataframe whose values are dependent on an exisiting column("Sum of Pillar".

->WithSumIDAPillars <- maml.mapInputPort(1)

->WithSumIDAPillars["newcolumn"] <- NA

->WithSumIDAPillars$newcolumn <- if (WithSumIDAPillars$Sum of Pillar <5 ="Low";WithSumIDAPillars$Sum of Pillar <=6<=10 ="Medium";WithSumIDAPillars$Sum of Pillar <=11<=16 ="High"

I need to create a new column that would set the following requirements:
If "Sum of PIllar" value is between 0-5=Low, 6-11=Medium and 11-16=High.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the dplyr package? Would something like this work?

```r
library("dplyr")

WithSumIDAPillars$newcolumn <- 
  case_when(
    WithSumIDAPillars$`Sum of Pillar` <= 6 ~ "Low",
    WithSumIDAPillars$`Sum of Pillar` <= 11 ~ "Medium",
    WithSumIDAPillars$`Sum of Pillar` <= 16 ~ "High",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )
```

The `case_when()` function goes through each case sequentially for until one of the expressions on the left side of the `~` evaluates to `TRUE`, so the last statement is used as a default value.

Depending on your application, it may make things easier to name your column `sum_of_pillar`, using underscores. That would make it easier to use the pipe (`%>%`) and the `mutate()` function to write things a little more concisely:

```r
WithSumIDAPillars <- 
  WithSumIDAPillars %>%
  mutate(
    newcolumn = case_when(
      sum_of_pillar <=  5 ~ "Low",
      sum_of_pillar <= 11 ~ "Medium",
      sum_of_pillar <= 16 ~ "High",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

To learn more about dplyr, you can visit the website: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ or the (free) R for Data Science Book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! I tried using this but Azure keeps giving me the Execute R Script Error; "could not find function "case_when"". Also tried renaming the column to "sum_of_pillar" but that also gave me the same error "could not find function "%>%".

Comment: Do you have **dplyr** installed? If not, you can `install.packages("dplyr")`.

Comment: This is the current code im using:                                                                 library("dplyr")
install.packages("dplyr")
Pillar$newcolumn <- 
  case_when(
    Pillar$sum_of_pillars <= 6 ~ "Low",
    Pillar$sum_of_pillars <= 11 ~ "Medium",
    Pillar$sum_of_pillars <= 16 ~ "High",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )

Comment: You need to `install.packages("dplyr")` before you can use `library("dplyr")`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, perhaps less elegant method to `case_when` is using nested `if_else` statements.  Maybe the one advantage is you don't have to may too much attention to the order or the statements as you do with `case_when`.

```
library(tidyverse)

WithSumIDAPillars %>%
    mutate(new_col = if_else(`Sum of the Pillar` >= 0 & <= 5, "Low",
                             if_else(`Sum of the Pillar` >= 6 & <= 11, "Medium",
                                     if_else(`Sum of the Pillar` >= 12 & <= 18, "High",
                                             NA))))
```

NB - there's an overlap between your upper Medium and lower High thresholds so I upped the lower boundary for High to 12.